# html5 - download attribute set filename undefined

Tags: javascript, html

This might be an opinionated question. The below sample code works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a id="downLink"></a>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function downloadFile(filename){
    var anchor = document.getElementById('downLink');
    anchor.setAttribute('href', filename);
    //anchor.setAttribute('download','');

    var icon = document.createElement('i');
    icon.className = 'fa fa-cloud';

    var icon1 = document.createElement('i');
    icon1.className = 'fa fa-car';

   anchor.append(icon);
   anchor.append(icon1);

    icon1.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('car clicked');
    });
    }

    downloadFile('SampleData_12_07_2017_00_08_00.xlsx');

    </script>
    </html>
```

When I use similar pattern with the production version of code, each time I am getting "download=undefined". Although I am able to download the file with filename "undefined.xlsx".

I tried to set download with anchor.setAttribute('download','') but still it is set to undefined on production code. Not putting `download` attribute without assigning any value.

Is it possible that chrome and Firefox set it to undefined ?

Comment: So, you're showing us code that works, then asking us to imagine different code that might or might not work?

Comment: @Mike McCaughan is there any restriction on filename by browser ?